# Upper case in section and toc

Tags: sectioning

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}
```

Using this package I can make section upper case:

```
\section{This will be upper case}
```

[image]

but in toc will be original text from section, is it possible to make uppercase also in toc?
[image]

Comment: Yes, you might  take a look at the companion package `titletoc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution without an additional package could be a new `\Section` command that changes both by using the `\section` command with uppercase text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\Section}[2][]{%
  \def\shortsec{#1}%
  \ifx\shortsec\empty%
    \section{\MakeUppercase{#2}}
  \else%
    \section[\MakeUppercase{#1}]{\MakeUppercase{#2}}
  \fi}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Section[t]{title}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

**edit:** to make it work with the `hyperref` package, one needs to adjust the code (with the `\ifdefined` line I modified the behavior, so it can be used with and without hyperref):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ifdefined\texorpdfstring\else\newcommand{\texorpdfstring}[2]{#1}\fi
\newcommand{\Section}[2][]{%
  \def\shortsec{#1}%
  \ifx\shortsec\empty%
    \section{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}
  \else%
    \section[\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}]{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}
  \fi}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Section{title}
\end{document}
```

Probably there is a more beautiful approach using lua(la)tex, I could look into that if someone is interested.

**edit2:** To substitute the old `\section` command, one could do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ifdefined\texorpdfstring\else\newcommand{\texorpdfstring}[2]{#1}\fi
\let\oldsection\section

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@ifstar{\@sSection}{\@Section}}
\newcommand{\@sSection}[2][]{%
  \oldsection*{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\@Section}[2][]{%
  \def\shortsec{#1}%
  \ifx\shortsec\empty%
    \oldsection{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}
  \else%
    \oldsection[\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}]{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{title}
\end{document}
```

**edit3:** In case you want to keep the old `\section*` behavior, e.g., to keep the old title of toc rather than an uppercase version, you can replace

```
\renewcommand{\section}{\@ifstar{\@sSection}{\@Section}}
```

with

```
\renewcommand{\section}{\@ifstar{\oldsection*}{\@Section}}
```

Comment: could you make code for `\Section{SectionName}` without second input -> `\Section{SectionName}{SectionName}` because data between this two `{}{}` should always be the same. Thank you :)

Comment: @Beginner Sorry, I do not understand this request, you can easily use `\Section{SectionName}` as usual. The only thing missing is currently a starred version `\Section*`, if you want I can add that.

Comment: sorry, I was confused with [t] inside of this code `\Section[t]{title}`. If I remove [t], data in toc and section will be the same. :)

Comment: @Beginner Indeed, this is just the short version of the section title. I wanted to show it's working with that as well. Usually you use this optional argument in case you have a (very) long section title that should appear shortened in the toc.

Comment: Very nice, thank you so much! But when I have implemented your code in my original document I have recieved this error **Undefined control sequence. \Section{This will be upper case}**. First I was testing with your example and everything is OK. This is my full code, if you have time can you see what is the issue? Thank you! https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mxjscoFgpcGyqcAztggI0o3wtaoESrel

Comment: @Beginner Sure, you are using the `hyperref` package, I'll update the code to make it compatible.